# "Proportional coalition function" coalitional game with fair splitting

Tags: terminology, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have a game that has a special form of payoff function of a coalitional game.

There is a set $N$ (of $n$ players) and a coalition function $v$ that maps subsets of players to the real numbers: $ v\colon \mathbf{P}(N) \to \mathbb {R} $, with $ v(\emptyset )=0$.

And in my setting, $v(S) = g(S) - c, S\subset N$. where $c$ is a constant and $g(\emptyset) = c$. And even nicely $g(S\cup \{i\}) = q_ig(S), \forall i \notin S$. And $q_i$ is a variable only depends on player $i$.

I'm wondering if there is a name for this type of game?

And one area I'm mostly interested in, in the game, is about splitting players.

Suppose i split/replace a player $i$ with the variable $q_i$ into two players $m,n$, with their variable $q_m, q_n$ where $q_m, q_n \neq 1$ and $q_m * q_n = q_i$. So now we have a game $N+1$ player. Using something like shapely value to divide the payoff is not going to be consistent, namely the value of $i$ in the $N$ game is different from the value for sum of $m$ and $n$ in the $N+1$ game.

Wondering what kind of payoff I can use for each player so it's consistent with or without such splitting ?  (players get the same with or without splitting).

Comment: Why do you suppose that the Shapely value is not consistent? The Shapely value is not a proportional distribution rule, it reflects the bargaining power of players. Adding a player by the rule you imposed does change the structure of the game -- i.e., the bargaining power of players -- and this change has an impact on the distributive arbitration of the Shapely value. It might be best to study the axiomatization of the Shapely value to have some kind of understanding of the attributed distribution rule.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt I guess my question is if there is any attribution value such that splitting/merging players won't impact the attribution?